# writing a simple shell script connecting to psql in cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin, psql

```bash
#!/bin/sh
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=mydb --username=usr_name << EOF
\i 'path_to_file/test.sql';
EOF
```

Trying to execute a psql sql script in bash using cygwin. It works well if I pass through simple select query with hostname but if I run as a proper shell script it takes time

Comment: Why the "here doc"? Why not pass the file using the `-f` parameter?

Comment: I am new to psql and shell scripting . Could you please tell me what is the mistake i made ?

Comment: It seems to me that `psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=mydb --username=usr_name -f path_to_file/test.sql` would be much simpler.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence in the question. I think it needs elaboration.

Comment: for path when i give as "C://Documents/test.sql" it throws no file or such directory . should i give within enclosed quotes?

Comment: great ! it worked .. thanks a lot..thanks once again

Comment: Since `C://Documents/test.sql` does not have embedded spaces, quotes are not needed. You can write it simpler as C:/Documents/test.sql; I don't see why you put two slashes, although they don't harm.

Comment: do not use path like `"C://Documents/test.sql"`. Use `cygpath -u "C://Documents/test.sql"` to obtain the proper POSIX form. However I doubt the file is in a "C://Documents/" directory, except you really created it. Your standard `Documents` is likely as `/cygdrive/C/Users/YOUR_USER_ID/Documents` in POSIX form.

Comment: Additional info at https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-win32

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `psql` command in here-doc without variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --dbname=mydb --username=usr_name<<'EOF'
\i 'path_to_file/test.sql';
EOF
```

Note the quote on the leading `'EOF'`